# Is it Possible to Use the Soot Analyses Without Calling soot.Main.main(...)?

Tags: java, api, static-analysis, soot

I want to use [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) to do a static analysis of Java programs, including for example the control flow graph.

The various [tutorials](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/tutorial/) say that the "standard way" to use Soot is to create a main method where one adds custom transforms to the Soot pipeline **and then call [soot.Main.main(...)](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/doc/soot/Main.html#main%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    PackManager.v().getPack("jtp").add(
         new Transform("jtp.gotoinstrumenter", GotoInstrumenter.v()));
    soot.Main.main(args);
}
```

Of course, this has some serious limitations if you want to use Soot in something else than a command line tool. For example, it is unclear to me whether it is even legal to call Soot's main method more than once in a program.

So does anyone know a possibility to use the Soot analysis tools directly through an API that is a bit more sophisticated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is yes. In your main you can set up the class that you working with:

```
configure("../yourClasspath/");
SootClass sootClass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport("className");
sootClass.setApplicationClass();

// Retrieve the method and its body
SootMethod m = c.getMethodByName("methodName");
Body b = m.retrieveActiveBody();

// Instruments bytecode
new YourTransform().transform(b);
```

After that, you might build the CFG and run some analysis.

It follows the configure method:

```
public static void configure(String classpath) {

        Options.v().set_verbose(false);
        Options.v().set_keep_line_number(true);
        Options.v().set_src_prec(Options.src_prec_class);
        Options.v().set_soot_classpath(classpath);
        Options.v().set_prepend_classpath(true);

        PhaseOptions.v().setPhaseOption("bb", "off");
        PhaseOptions.v().setPhaseOption("tag.ln", "on");
        PhaseOptions.v().setPhaseOption("jj.a", "on");
        PhaseOptions.v().setPhaseOption("jj.ule", "on");

        Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I asked this question I learned a lot about Soot. I found the `G.reset()` very useful for unit tests.

Comment: `m.retrieveActiveBody()` also retains method annotations through `SootMethod.getTags()`. While this is not present in the `jtp` phase (only in the `jap` phase) when invoked from `soot.Main` directly, it is present when retrieved in thi smanner.